# Compile/run assembler in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x86, assembly

I'm fairly new to Linux (Ubuntu 10.04) and a total novice to assembler. I was following some tutorials and I couldn't find anything specific to Linux.
So, my question is, what is a good package to compile/run assembler and what are the command line commands to compile/run for that package?

Comment: I'm in the same boat. I've never really picked up asm on Linux because there's no real presence. Maybe it's because on Windows cracking is all the rage.

Comment: These don't completely answer my question. I still want to know what console commands you would use to compile and run programs in NASM or gas

Comment: My preference is NASM.  I give you some info on how to get it up and running on Ubuntu below.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The GNU assembler (gas) and NASM are both good choices. However, they have some differences, the big one being the order you put operations and their operands.

gas uses AT&T syntax (guide: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/att/info):

```
mnemonic    source, destination
```

nasm uses Intel style (guide: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/intel-syntax/info):

```
mnemonic    destination, source
```

Either one will probably do what you need.  GAS also has an Intel-syntax mode, which is a lot like MASM, not NASM.

---

Try out this tutorial:  http://asm.sourceforge.net/intro/Assembly-Intro.html

See also more links to guides and docs in Stack Overflow's [x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)

Comment: Thanks, that tutorial is great since it's linux specific. Also, the tutorial had very specific instructions on how to compile and run assembler progs in linux

Comment: gas has supported ".intel_syntax" for a while - I'd personally still use fasm, yasm or nasm though.

Answer (score 63):

The GNU assembler is probably already installed on your system. Try `man as` to see full usage information. You can use `as` to compile individual files and ld to link if you really, really want to.

However, GCC makes a great front-end. It can assemble .s files for you. For example:

```
$ cat >hello.s <<"EOF"
.section .rodata             # read-only static data
.globl hello
hello:
  .string "Hello, world!"    # zero-terminated C string

.text
.global main
main:
    push    %rbp
    mov     %rsp,  %rbp                 # create a stack frame

    mov     $hello, %edi                # put the address of hello into RDI
    call    puts                        #  as the first arg for puts

    mov     $0,    %eax                 # return value = 0.  Normally xor %eax,%eax
    leave                               # tear down the stack frame
    ret                            # pop the return address off the stack into RIP
EOF
$ gcc hello.s -no-pie -o hello
$ ./hello
Hello, world!
```

The code above is x86-64.  If you want to make a position-independent executable (PIE), you'd need `lea hello(%rip), %rdi`, and `call puts@plt`.

A non-PIE executable (position-*dependent*) can use 32-bit absolute addressing for static data, but a PIE should use RIP-relative LEA.  (See also [Difference between movq and movabsq in x86-64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315803/difference-between-movq-and-movabsq-in-x86-64) neither `movq` nor `movabsq` are a good choice.)

If you wanted to write 32-bit code, the calling convention is different, and RIP-relative addressing isn't available.  (So you'd `push $hello` before the call, and pop the stack args after.)

---

You can also compile C/C++ code directly to assembly if you're curious how something works:

```
$ cat >hello.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;
}
EOF
$ gcc -S hello.c -o hello.s
```

See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) for more about looking at compiler output, and writing useful small functions that will compile to interesting output.

Answer (score 20):

If you are using NASM, the command-line is just

```
nasm -felf32 -g -Fdwarf file.asm -o file.o
```

where 'file.asm' is your assembly file (code) and 'file.o' is an object file you can link with `gcc -m32` or `ld -melf_i386`.  (Assembling with `nasm -felf64` will make a 64-bit object file, but the hello world example below uses 32-bit system calls, and won't work in a PIE executable.)

Here is some more info:

http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.1

You can install NASM in Ubuntu with the following command:

```
apt-get install nasm
```

Here is a basic Hello World in Linux assembly to whet your appetite:

http://web.archive.org/web/20120822144129/http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~if817/arquivos/asmtut/index.html

I hope this is what you were asking...

Comment: Hello World example is a broken link!

Answer (score 8):

There is also FASM for Linux.

```
format ELF executable

segment readable executable

start:
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, hello_msg
mov edx, hello_size
int 80h

mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 80h

segment readable writeable

hello_msg db "Hello World!",10,0
hello_size = $-hello_msg
```

It comiles with

```
fasm hello.asm hello
```

Answer (score 7):

My suggestion would be to get the book Programming From Ground Up:

http://nongnu.askapache.com/pgubook/ProgrammingGroundUp-1-0-booksize.pdf

That is a very good starting point for getting into assembler programming under linux and it explains a lot of the basics you need to understand to get started.

Answer (score 4):

3 syntax (nasm, tasm, gas ) in 1 assembler, yasm.

http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/

Answer (score 3):

The assembler(GNU) is **as(1)**

Answer (score 3):

For **Ubuntu 18.04** install`nasm` . Open the terminal and type:

`sudo apt install as31 nasm`

[**nasm**](https://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoci.html) docs

For compiling and running:

```
nasm -f elf64 example.asm # assemble the program  
ld -s -o example example.o # link the object file nasm produced into an executable file  
./example # example is an executable file
```

Comment: as31 is an assembler for 8051 code.  Linux doesn't run on 8051 microcontrollers, so you can't link and then *run* anything you assemble with it right on your Linux machine (which is what this question was about).

Comment: @Geancarlo Murillo This is just the best answer. Thank you so much. This worked perfectly. Just exactly what I needed!